# How to prevent a function from being imported into another module in python

Tags: python, module

How can we restrict other modules from importing certain functions while allowing others.

Desired behavior

```py
# module A: a.py
def foo():
  print('foo')

def bar():
  print('bar')


# module B: b.py
from a import foo # error, foo not found in a
from a import bar # okay!
```

EDIT:

When someone writes `from a import foo` they should get error of some sorts. This way I can restrict people from importing functions that are meant to be only called from the functions in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
def foo():
    if __name__ != "__main__":
        print("cant run")
```

> [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)